# Passing a 2D array of structs

Tags: c, pointers, multidimensional-array, struct

Im dealing out card type structures from an array.

```
struct card deck[DECKSIZE];  //The deck is an array of cards structures
```

Im using a 2D array. An array of arrays of card type structures

```
struct card allHands[hands][cards];
```

Im using this function passing the deck and the array as pointers with the parameters of the array. I also change the location of the deck pointer to simulate the deck losing the card as it is passed to the player.

```
void dealHands(struct card *deck, struct card **handArray, int hands, int cards){

    int players;
    int cardCount;
    int passCard = 0;
    struct card * thisDeck;

    thisDeck = deck;

    for(players = 0; players < hands; players++){
        for(cardCount = 0; cardCount < cards; cardCount++){
            handArray[players][cardCount] = thisDeck[passCard];
            passCard++;
        }   
    }
    deck = (deck + passCard);   
}
```

Its been a long while that I program in c so I think this is how you do the prototype?

```
    void dealHands(struct card[], struct card*[], int, int);
```

This is like the skeleton of my main of how Im implementing the function.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    /* Declare and initialize variables  */

    int hands = atoi(argv[HANDSINPUT]);  //How many players 
    int cards = atoi(argv[CARDSINPUT]);  //How many cards per hand  
    struct card deck[DECKSIZE];  //The deck is an array of cards structures

    struct card allHands[hands][cards];

    //Builds the deck
    //Shuffles deck with a RNG and swapping every card

    int players;
    int cardCount;
    int passCard = 0;   


    dealHands(deck, allHands, hands, cards);


}
```

I get the 2 following statements during compilation

warning: passing argument 2 of ‘dealHands’ from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
  dealHands(deck, allHands, hands, cards);
  ^

note: expected ‘struct card **’ but argument is of type ‘struct card (*)[(sizetype)(cards)]’
 void dealHands(struct card[], struct card*[], int, int);
      ^

I always mess up when it comes to pointers and arrays when I need to call them in a function. So Im not sure where my logic is flawed. Where am I passing the address rather than the value or vice versa?

Comment: `struct card **` cannot get a 2D array. A pointer is not an array! Use the corect declaration for the argument as the warning implies.

Comment: @Olaf thats the thing. I dont recall on how to properly declare it. if its 
struct card *handArray[] or struct card handArray[][] or something else. I cant seem to find it :/

Comment: You noticed I posted quite a comprehensive answer, didn't you?

Comment: No sorry my bad. @Olaf 
Im not used to the interface yet.

Comment: Please take the [tour]. As always, you are expected to know how to use SO.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The most important thing when passing arrays as function arguments is: **You can't pass an array to/from a function**.

Said that, read the following very carefully. (I'll use `int` for simplicity, but of course you can use other types, too.)

But you can pass a "pointer to the first element" of an array. Luckily, C does the conversion automatically. Even more, for all but three exceptions (`sizeof`, `_Alignof`, `&` operators), C converts the name of an array automatically to such a pointer. This is often called "the array *decays* to a pointer to the first element".

But this decaying is not recursive. So, if you pass a 2D array to a function, it decays to a pointer to a 1D array:

```
int a[1][2];    // 1 = outer dimension, 2 = inner
```

when passed to a function

```
void f(int a[1][2]);
```

becomes

```
int (*a)[2]   // pointer to array of inner dimension
```

Alternatively one can explicitly use pointer syntax

```
void f(int (*a)[2]);
```

The type of `a` is `int (*)[2]` for all cases. Mind the parentheses! Which syntax you use is basically personal preference. I do prefer the array syntax with all dimensions, because that documents the intention more clearly.

You always have to pass all sizes, except for the outermost dimension. That is just for documentation and not required (see below for an example).

Inside the function, you use normal index-operator:

```
int t, i;    // index variable for ouTer, Inner
a[t][i];
```

Note this can be applied to higher dimension arrays. For 1D array, this also applies, actually. Just remove the inner dimension:

```
int a[1];
```

decays to

```
int *a;
```

(I just used the constants `1` and `2` to number the dimensions; of course you can use the dimensions you want.)

---

If you want to pass an array with variable length (VLA, _variable length array), you have to pass all but the outermost dimension to the function:

```
f(int inner, a[][inner]);
```

But better for checking, etc. is to pass all dimensions:

```
f(int outer, int inner, a[outer][inner]);
```

Comment: Thank you. It compiled successfully.
The prototype ends with struct card[][MAXCARDS]
and the function is struct card handArray[hands][cards] 
I had a small problem with the dealCards function. But now I reread the answer and I realized my mistake. Thank you very much for the information.

Answer (score -2):

All of this might be a bit of a pain to understand, but it's pretty easy once you experiment around with it. You see, you can never pass a whole array as an argument (I mean you kinda could, by passing every single element, but that isn't the point). An array is basically sort of a table. If it's 1D, you have a line of boxes. If it's 2D, you have a table of boxes. If it's 3D, you have a cub(e/oid) of boxes. What you could do though is exploit how the numbers are laid out in memory and use pointer arithmetic. It's quite simple.

Ok, let's go-

Let's say we have a function, set_up_array, which takes a pointer to a 2D array as a parameter.

```
void set_up_array(int **array, int row_size, int column_size){
    for(int i = 0; i < row_size; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < column_size; j++){
            *((int*)array + i*row_size + j) = i + j + k;
        }
    }
}
```

That might make you freak out, but stay with me here okay.

Now, imagine the 2D array you're passing as a table. It's got rows, and then it's got columns. How would you go to the next element in such a table? Well, you have the index of your element, and you find it out, right? That's eactly what we're doing here.
I'll start of by explaining the reason we're typecasting array to int*. It's quite simple. Whenever we do pointer math, the C compiler tries to ease up our work (like a real bud...), so instead of adding the address to the pointers, we simply add the number of elements, and based on that, the C compiler will automatically figure out the address we want. Now, here's the problem, the C compiler figures that out by finding out the size of the what type the pointer points to. So, in order to make our lives simple, and also to make the C compiler happy, we convert it into a int*, which means, from here on, whatever we add will add to the initial address like it'd with int*s.
Now let's go back to the table analogy. We know the row number and the column number.
[image] 
One thing you might wanna keep in mind is that this image has the column and row labels reversed

To make our lives even more simpler, let's switch to a cartesian view (A graph-ish view, with an x and a y coordinate). Let's say that x is horizontal, while y is vertical. We can then write the arrray as 

`array[y][x]`
Which means that the element which we want, is the `x*row_size + y` element.
Which we can basically add to the pointer in our function, and the dereference it, like it's been done, just there, we used i and j.

Comment: `int **` is **not** a 2D array! It is a pointer to pointer - very different data structure (it just happens to have the same syntax to access the elements). It does not match the layout in the picture.

Comment: Okay..., wow, I thought that was the case for a long time, since a 2d array could be broken down in to an array of arrays, and as such, a pointer to a pointer. Could you please elaborate?

Comment: To repeat that: An array is **not** a pointer. See my answer for correctly passing an array of any number of dimensions. Also do **only** cast **iff** 1) they are really required 2) you understand **all** implications and 3) accept them **fully**.

Comment: @Olaf Uh... So where's the problem? I know that an array is a contiguous block of data. And passing it is impossible. Infact even using it is impossible. We need pointer arithmetic, and the pointer to the first element. That's why I said the a 2D array should decay into a pointer to a pointer (a pointer to an array, which in turn decays to pointer to a pointer)

Comment: Last time repeat: If you read my answer **very** carefully (I think I wrote that in the answer), you will see where you are wrong. If a **specific** information is missing, feel free to drop a comment (where appropriate). If you don't understand the basics there - no offence - , please understand stack overflow is not a tutorial site. In that case you should read a god (and more recent than K&R) C book.

Comment: I have a feeling that you've misunderstood my post. I never said that an int** is an array, but I've used it to define functions as long as I can remember, and also the books I read had the same syntax

Comment: No, I have not missunderstood. But just as this is shown in books does not make it a 2D array, nor is it correct. If that makes you feel better: pointers to pointers and multi-dimensional arrays are one of the most missunderstood and confused concepts in C. Btw. you don't even use that correctly. You basically use a 1D array inside your code with manual indexing. But the object you pass is not even a 1D `int` array, but - at best - an array of pointers, i.e. `int *[]`. A 2D array decays to  `int (*)[]`, though, as I wrote in my answer.