# C pointers with Structs and 2D Arrays

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, struct

I am confused on how these C pointers work.

Here is what I am trying to do:

Create a struct that has a row, column, and grid (2d array of predefined size).

```
typedef struct 
    {
        int row;
        int column;
        int (*matrix)[GRID_SIZE];
    } parameters;
```

Now I create one

```
int grid[GRID_SIZE][GRID_SIZE] = {
    {6, 5, 3, 1, 2, 8, 7, 9, 4},
    {1, 7, 4, 3, 5, 9, 6, 8, 2},
    {9, 2, 8, 4, 6, 7, 5, 3, 1},
    {2, 8, 6, 5, 1, 4, 3, 7, 9},
    {3, 9, 1, 7, 8, 2, 4, 5, 6},
    {5, 4, 7, 6, 9, 3, 2, 1, 8},
    {8, 6, 5, 2, 3, 1, 9, 4, 7},
    {4, 1, 2, 9, 7, 5, 8, 6, 3},
    {7, 3, 9, 8, 4, 6, 1, 2, 5}};
parameters *data = (parameters *) malloc(sizeof(parameters)); 
data->row = 1;
data->column = 2;
data->matrix = grid; // is this right?

int** test = data->matrix; //this is wrong.
```

My goal is to pass in that struct as data when creating a new thread. I am really clueless on how the pointer system works when creating the 2D array in the struct and then using it later. Any help is appreciated.

Edit... here is my new code.. looks like its working! :)

```
parameters *data = malloc(sizeof(parameters)); //make sure to free thread after
data->row = 1;
data->column = 2;
data->matrix = grid;

int (*test)[GRID_SIZE] = data->matrix;

printf("first value, %d\n", test[0][0]);
```

Comment: 1) Don't cast the result of `malloc` & friends in C. 2) `int **` cannot reference a 2D array. A pointer is not an array.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing a 2D array of structs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35614862/passing-a-2d-array-of-structs)

Comment: If you pass `data` to a thread then remember that that won't copy anything, and you must make sure you do not access the `grid` concurrently from two different threads without synchronization

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work.
Define your struct like this:

```
typedef struct 
{
    int row;
    int column;
    int matrix[GRID_SIZE][GRID_SIZE];
} parameters;
```

Copy the matrix like this:

```
memcpy( data->matrix, grid, sizeof(grid) );
```