# how to pass a 3d array of pointers to a function in c?

Tags: c, arrays, function, multidimensional-array

I am having problem in this situation

```
typedef struct {  
   ...
} str;

str *matrix[SIZE][SIZE][SIZE];

for (i = ...) {
    for (j = ...) {
        for (k = ...) {
            matrix[i][j][k] = (str *)malloc(NUM * sizeof(str));
        }
    }
}
```

and successfully get access to this 3D array by

```
( (matrix[i][j][k])[n] ) //  in n-th element.
```

My question is ,how can I pass this 3D array of pointers (to struct str) in a function in my program?

Comment: Maybe an [answer of mine](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35615201/4774918) can help (the dup uses a fixed-dimension array). Note I try to explain a general rule for N-dimensional arrays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try the obvious syntaxes:

Accessing the `n`th structure:

```
matrix[i][j][k][n].member = value;
```

Receiving the 3D matrix:

```
void myfunc(str *a[SIZE][SIZE][SIZE]) {
    ...
    a[i][j][k][n].member = value;
    ...
}
```

Note that the first `SIZE` is ignored, arrays decay as pointers when passed to functions, the function argument could be defined as `str *a[][SIZE][SIZE]` or `str *(*a)[SIZE][SIZE]` with the exact same semantics.

Passing it:

```
myfunc(matrix);
```

Comment: Thank you , your help was simple and nice :)

Answer (score 0):

> My question is ,how can i pass this 3d array of pointers (to struct str) in a function in my program?

The argument type of the function needs to be

```
str *matrix[SIZE][SIZE][SIZE]
```

or

```
str *matrix[][SIZE][SIZE]
```

or

```
str * (*matrix)[SIZE][SIZE]
```

Example:

```
#define SIZE 10

typedef struct s str;

void foo(str* m[SIZE][SIZE][SIZE])
{
}

void bar(str* m[][SIZE][SIZE])
{
}

void baz(str* (*m)[SIZE][SIZE])
{
}

int main()
{
   str* m[SIZE][SIZE][SIZE];
   foo(m);
   bar(m);
   baz(m);
}
```

Comment: Thank you , your help was simple and nice :)