# C: Why freeing int** array isn't complete?

Tags: c, arrays

I allocate memory for my 2d array, it works... but not correctly. When I use valgrind to see if I allocate and free well my array, I see that I free only 29 blocs on 445. The other problem is that my array got 11 columns for 20 lines, so 220 blocs I think.
My results aren't correct, isn't it? How can I fix it?

There is my code, thank you in advance for your answers.

**EDIT:** My program should work with ncurses library. Should I really remove all what is link to?

There is all my code this time:

```
#include <ncurses.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(void) {
    initscr();
    noecho();
    curs_set(0);
    keypad(stdscr, TRUE);
    if (init_board() == -1)
        return (-1);
    while (1)
        refresh();
    endwin();
    return (0);
}

void print_board(int **tab) {
    int i;
    int line;

    i = 0;
    printw("------------\n");
    while (i < 20) {
        line = 11;
        printw("| ");
        while (line-- > 0) {
            tab[i][line] = 0;
            if (tab[i][line] == 0)
                printw("* ");
        }
        printw("|\n");
        i++;
    }
    wprintw(stdscr, "------------\n");
}

int **board_size(int **tab) {
    int i;

    i = 0;
    while (i < 20) {
        if ((tab[i] = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int) * 11)) == NULL) {
            wprintw(stdscr, "%s\n", "Second malloc's tab failed.");
            return (NULL);
        }
        i++;
    }
    return (tab);
}

void free_board(int **tab) {
    int   i;

    i = 0;
    while (i < 20) {
        printw("%d\n", i);
        free(tab[i]);
        i++;
    }
    free(tab);
}

int init_board() {
    int **tab;

    tab = NULL;
    if ((tab = (int **)malloc(sizeof(int*) * 20)) == NULL) {
        wprintw(stdscr, "%s\n", "First malloc's tab failed.");
         return (-1);
    }
    if ((tab = board_size(tab)) == NULL)
        return (-1);
    print_board(tab);
    free_board(tab);
    return (0);
}
```

Comment: I don't see any *obvious* mistakes.  Please post a *complete program* that we can compile for ourselves.  Please also remove all uses of the nonstandard `printw`, `wprintw`, `stdscr`, etc. as they distract from the question.

Comment: `int **` is not a 2D array, but a "pointer to pointer to int". It cannot even point to a 2D array. And don't cast the result of `malloc` & friends in C. If you want a 2D array, why not use one?

Comment: There is no need to return an `int**` from `board_size` as `board_size` manipulates `tab` directly.

Comment: I edited my post to add more precision about my code. But I think I understand the problem, I didn't think I didn't use a 2d array... I have a lot of things to learn about C (:

Comment: @Olaf This is the "dope vector" idiom.  The resulting group of objects can be used as a 2D array, and AFAIK you _have_ to do something like this when both dimensions of the array are determined at runtime; the 2D arrays you're thinking of can only have _one_ runtime-variable dimension.

Comment: @Eino You needn't edit out the ncurses stuff.  I wouldn't have said that if you had posted a complete program in the first place, because then I would have known it was ncurses stuff.

Comment: @zwol: It cannot be used as 2D array. It just has the same syntax, but very different implications, e.g. for allocation/free (which is a recurring problem here) and for performance (fragmentation, locality, alignment), depending on the algorithm. And you can very well use a VLA with multiple dimensions fixed. But for a 2D array, a simple `int (*)[inner_dim]` is sufficient ("pointer to 1D VLA"). I elaborated on that in an [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35615201/4774918)

Comment: @Olaf VLAs are still very poorly supported and IMNSHO should not be used in portable code.  It's possible to avoid most of the problems you're thinking of by allocating the storage for the pseudo-2D array in one big block and then carving it up.  And the statement "It cannot be used as a 2D array" is technically true but will lead someone at the OP's level of understanding toward further confusion, not toward enlightenment.

Comment: @zwol: VLAs are part of the C standard. C99 is now 17 years old, and any modern compiler supports it (actually it should be C11, but the commitee made the stupid decission to make them optional; anyway most compilers support both versions if any). If not use a modern compiler. Telling a beginner this is not an 2D array and does not have the same implications is not confusing. On the contrary, stating that this is a 2D array as done here by people who should know better actually is. Only if one understands the implications, it is possible to decide which approach to use.

Comment: @Olaf The fact that C11 made this feature of C99 optional should tell you something about how unenthusiastic compiler vendors have been about picking it up. Re pedagogy, you told a beginner that something indexable as `[x][y]` "isn't a 2D array," without any further explanation. How can this possibly _not_ lead to confusion?

Comment: @zwol: Not really. There is only one compiler vendor who likely initiated that breaking with the commitees normal approach of keeping older features, however obsolete they have become. About the didactics: This is not school, nor a tutorial site. A poster can very well be expected to do learn on his own. The difference is emphasised in every good C book. Also there are enough posts on SO about this subject already. Yesterday e.g. there were at least 3 new posts.

Comment: @Olaf You are wrong on all counts and I am done arguing with you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with your code, and you are freeing all memory you allocate. What you do not, and cannot control is the memory allocated by the *curses library* for managing the various windows and curses environment. For example:

**valgrind Output**

```
$ valgrind ./bin/board
==18521== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==18521== Copyright (C) 2002-2013, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==18521== Using Valgrind-3.10.1 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==18521== Command: ./bin/board
==18521==
==18521==
==18521== HEAP SUMMARY:
==18521==     in use at exit: 199,908 bytes in 440 blocks
==18521==   total heap usage: 468 allocs, 28 frees, 205,540 bytes allocated
==18521==
==18521== LEAK SUMMARY:
==18521==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==18521==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==18521==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==18521==    still reachable: 199,908 bytes in 440 blocks
==18521==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==18521== Rerun with --leak-check=full to see details of leaked memory
==18521==
==18521== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==18521== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 1 from 1)
```

You are allocating `1040` bytes (on x86_64) (`960` bytes on x86) for your `220` integers and `20` pointers. You have no control over the remaining `~198,000` bytes allocated by routines in the curses library.

So you are not going crazy and you are freeing what you are supposed to. When you program with a library that allocates blocks of memory, you should check if there is a `valgrind` pattern or exclusion file that will exclude the curses allocation (much like is done for GTK/glib) Windowed environments pre-allocate large blocks to handle the various tasks they preform. That memory will always be shown as still in use when your code exits. (the library may or may not tidy up before the ultimate exit of the program).

However, as others have pointed out, you should not cast the return of `malloc`. See: [**Do I cast the result of malloc?**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/995714) for thorough explanation. Your allocations should more properly be, e.g.:

```
if ((tab = malloc (sizeof *tab * 20)) == NULL) {
...
    if ((tab[i] = malloc (sizeof **tab * 11)) == NULL) {
```

Answer (score 0):

This answer is not correct. I did't realize that pointers array is allocated in one routine and integers arrays are allocated in other routine.

> You do `malloc` in `board_size` and in `initialize_board`. Former doesn't allocate array of pointers. Looks strange.

As was [mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35879726/c-why-freeing-int-array-isnt-complete/35879843#comment59422810_35879726), try to remove everything unrelated first. It's possible that some libraries allocate memory on initialization and don't release it until program terminates.

By the way, it's easier and more effective to allocate n*m once array than allocate n+1 arrays.

Comment: Can you explain me more clearly what do you mean by "allocate n*m once array than allocate n+1 arrays" please? I'm not sure to understand :s

Comment: @Eino allocate once array of 220 integers and access as `a[row*20+column]`.

Comment: Why two **free()** statements ?

Comment: And two **malloc ()** statements, which don't pair with the **free()** statements.

Comment: @George Thank you, I'll try it!

Comment: @Eino glad it helped you.

Comment: @ArifBurhan I use free first time for all the lines I allocated, in a loop, then for the column I allocated at beginning.