# Prototype to for updating pointer to 2D array with unknown dimensions

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array

I want to define an interface that takes a pointer to a pointer to an array of unknown size.  The function body should populate this array with an already statically-allocated array.

The problem is, the array I'm passing is part of a 2D array with one dimension unknown:

```
T_MY_STRUCT (*pMyConfigArray)[][2];
```

I only want to update along the known dimension per call to the interface.

And the pre-allocated array is defined in another file (the reason for the interface) as follows (The dimension with `2` is known, but the `10` is unknown by the calling side):

```
T_MY_STRUCT preAllocatedArray[2][10] = 
{
  {
    {0,TRUE,0,1,&dummyParam[0]},
    {1,TRUE,1,1,&dummyParam[1]},
    {2,TRUE,2,1,&dummyParam[2]},
    {3,TRUE,3,1,&dummyParam[3]},
    {4,TRUE,4,1,&dummyParam[4]},
    {5,TRUE,5,1,&dummyParam[5]},
    {6,TRUE,6,1,&dummyParam[6]},
    {7,TRUE,7,1,&dummyParam[7]},
    {8,TRUE,8,1,&dummyParam[8]},
    {9,TRUE,9,1,&dummyParam[9]}
  },
  {
    {0,TRUE, 0,1,&dummyParam[0]},
    {1,FALSE,1,1,&dummyParam[1]},
    {2,TRUE, 2,1,&dummyParam[2]},
    {3,FALSE,3,1,&dummyParam[3]},
    {4,TRUE, 4,1,&dummyParam[4]},
    {5,FALSE,5,1,&dummyParam[5]},
    {6,TRUE, 6,1,&dummyParam[6]},
    {7,FALSE,7,1,&dummyParam[7]},
    {8,TRUE, 8,1,&dummyParam[8]},
    {9,FALSE,9,1,&dummyParam[9]}
  }
};
```

The interfacing function to allow the structure "copying" is implemented as the following:

```
int retrieveConfigArray(int arrayIndex, T_MY_STRUCT (**configTab)[])
{
  int nbParam = 0;

  if ((configTab != NULL_VOID_PTR) && (arrayIndex < 2))
  {
    *configTab = &(preAllocatedArray[mmsPid]);
    nbParam = 10;
  }

  return nbParam;
}
```

And I pass the `pMyConfigArray`'s address to this function so it can be updated:

```
retrieveConfigArray(0, &(pMyConfigArray[][0])) /* Error Here */
retrieveConfigArray(1, &(pMyConfigArray[][1])) /* Error Here */
```

My question is, how can I define these array definitions/declarations as well as the function prototype to get the desired behavior?  As above I receive
`error: invalid use of array with unspecified bounds` on the line where I pass the array.  How can I utilize the array-pointer decaying and address-of operator to pass a pointer to the correct dimension here that matches the interface function prototype?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35614862/passing-a-2d-array-of-structs/35615201#35615201

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem I was having was related to how I declared the pointer to the array `pMyConfigArray`. I had defined it as a pointer to a 2D array of `T_MY_STRUCT` structs:

```
T_MY_STRUCT (*pMyConfigArray)[][2];
```

In fact what I required was an array of pointers to an array of structs:

```
T_MY_STRUCT (*pMyConfigArray[])[2] = {NULL, NULL};
```

This semantic difference uses a different declaration syntax, and must be initialised.

This resource in the [C Wikibook](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C_Programming/Pointers_and_arrays) may prove useful to people in a similar situation. It lists various array/pointer constructs for reference:

```
int i;         // integer variable 'i'
int *p;        // pointer 'p' to an integer
int a[];       // array 'a' of integers
int f();       // function 'f' with return value of type integer
int **pp;      // pointer 'pp' to a pointer to an integer
int (*pa)[];   // pointer 'pa' to an array of integer
int (*pf)();   // pointer 'pf' to a function with return value integer
int *ap[];     // array 'ap' of pointers to an integer
int *fp();     // function 'fp' which returns a pointer to an integer
int ***ppp;    // pointer 'ppp' to a pointer to a pointer to an integer
int (**ppa)[]; // pointer 'ppa' to a pointer to an array of integers
int (**ppf)(); // pointer 'ppf' to a pointer to a function with return value of type integer
int *(*pap)[]; // pointer 'pap' to an array of pointers to an integer
int *(*pfp)(); // pointer 'pfp' to function with return value of type pointer to an integer
int **app[];   // array of pointers 'app' that point to pointers to integer values
int (*apa[])[];// array of pointers 'apa' to arrays of integers
int (*apf[])();// array of pointers 'apf' to functions with return values of type integer
int ***fpp();  // function 'fpp' which returns a pointer to a pointer to a pointer to an int
int (*fpa())[];// function 'fpa' with return value of a pointer to array of integers
int (*fpf())();// function 'fpf' with return value of a pointer to function which returns an integer
```