# Declaring multidimensional array in C with VLA

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array

In my C textbook it it stated that the following can be used to declare and allocate a matrix `a` of size `mxn` (provided VLA:s are supported)

```
double (*a)[n];
a = malloc(m*n*sizeof(double));
a[2][3] = 3.141592653;
```

I understand that `a` is a pointer, so the compiler only needs to allocate memory for a pointer. What I don't understand is the role of `n` in the declaration of `a`. Is this information used in any way by the compiler? It doesn't affect the size of `a`, which is just the size of a double pointer, and eventually we let `a` point to a memory area larger than `n` (provided `m > 1`).

Comment: it affects the pointer arithmetics on `a`. say `a+1` moves the pointer by the size of an array of n `int`s

Comment: `a` is a pointer to a 1D array with `n` elements. Apparently you need the `n` to let the compiler know `sizeof(&a)`. A better way to get the size inside `malloc` is the ideomatic `m * sizeof(*a)`. That works whatever type `a` points to.

Comment: @user3528438 Ok, thanks that makes sense!

Comment: @Olaf Ok, very nice. Thanks!

Comment: Understand the design pattern and the concept and you are in the small company of C programmers who really mastered VLAs and pointers :-). I don't think it is not **that** complicated, but requires some thinking to understand all implications of pointer, arrays and the syntax. Hint: `double *a[n]` is something very different (and what many ppl **think** is a 2D array - they could hardly be more wrong).

Comment: @Olaf It is an array of `n` double pointers, right?

Comment: We don't call it a "double pointer" because a lot of people seems to call "T **" a "double pointer (to type T)". I usually call it a "pointer to double" to avoid the confusion.

Comment: Well, in the first place. But of course you can apply pointer arithmetic to them, too. Just understand that the index-operator `[]` in C is **always** applied to pointers, not to arrays! Then keep in mind arrays are for **most** operations implicitly converted to a pointer, but they are no pointers. So much for deeper info. I have an answer for a similar subject here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35614862/passing-a-2d-array-of-structs/35615201#35615201

Comment: @user3528438 Ok, thanks! I can see how it would be confusing.

Comment: @Olaf Thanks! Yes, the index operator is quite funny, e.g. `a[i] == i[a] ` :)

Comment: It is exactly the same as `a + i`. So, no it is not **that** funny, but a logical conclusion. But it is a good thing to confuse your teacher `printf("%c", 1["Hello"]);`. Warning: be prepared to explain it to him!