# How to pass an array of structs into a function using pointers?

Tags: c, pointers

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct{
    int lab;
    int arr[20];
    int vac;
}bookings;

void checkIn(bookings *in)
{
    printf("It is %i",in[0].arr[0]);
}

int main(){
    bookings b[5];
    int a,c;
    /*Initializing struct variables*/
    for(a=0;a<5;a++)
    {
        for(c=0;c<20;c++)
        {
            b[a].arr[c]=0;
            b[a].vac=20;
            /*printf("Lab %i PC %i is %i\n",a,c,b[a].arr[c]);*/
        }
        /*printf("Lab %i has vacant %i\n",a,b[a].vac);*/
    }
    b[0].lab=101;
    b[1].lab=201;
    b[2].lab=301;
    b[3].lab=401;
    b[4].lab=501;
    checkIn(&b);

    return 0;
}
```

Based on the code, I've assigned values of 0 into the arr[20] array and in each struct, the vac value will be 20. What I'm trying to do is to pass the array of structs into the function and read the value in the function. According to what I've read so far, using the pointers in the function parameters and passing the array of struct address should work.

When compiled, it displays the error,'error passing argument1 of checkIn from incompatible pointer type'.
My expected output is

```
It is 0
```

Any help would be quite appreciated!

Comment: Could you explain the difference of your question to this one? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35614862/passing-a-2d-array-of-structs?rq=1 I am not saying that it is a duplicate, but maybe it is close enough to be helpful.

Comment: Either `checkIn(b)` or `checkIn(&b[0])` should work.

Comment: Should be `checkIn(b)` not address of `b`, you're currently technically passing in a pointer to a pointer to the first element

Comment: @Jose Fernando Lopez Fernandez so the struct passed into the function is already an address in itself? Sorry, I'm still fresh with pointers and structs.

Comment: @cswannabe only because it's an array. Otherwise the struct would be passed by value

Comment: interesting enough, this works in GCC\clang. The error is caused by -pedantic flag of compiler. Normally such argument passed is just a warning (to be compatible old code or extensions)

Comment: [Ton of duplicates to this here](https://www.google.com/search?q=pass+an+array+of+strcut+to+a+function+site%3Astackoverflow.com).

Answer (score 4):

The expression `&b` gives the address of the `b` *array*, not the first element. They are at the same location in memory, but the type is different. `&b` has type `bookings (*)[5]`; that is, a pointer to an array of five `bookings`es. Your function wants just `bookings*` (pointer to either a single `bookings` or the start of an array of an unknown number of them). You can get this with *array-to-pointer decay* by skipping the `&` and just passing `b`, or by looking at `&(b[0])`, the address of the first element of the array.

Answer (score 3):

You need to pass the array without `&` - `checkIn(b)`;

When there is `&` the array doesn't convert to a pointer to the first element and the type is `bookings (*)[5]`.The function expect `bookings*` and you get a warning.

Without `&` the array decays to a pointer and the expected type is correct.

Comment: Why shouldn't I use `&` when passing the struct into the function?

Comment: @cswannabe the array name represents the address of the first element, similar to how the name of a function represents the function address

Answer (score 2):

It should be:

```
checkIn(b);
```

`&b` would return type of `bookings(*)[5]`. It would be useful if you need to modify your array (not its elements, they already passed by reference).

Comment: The types `bookings**` and `bookings (*)[5]` are different and incompatible, and `&b` is the latter. The first requires the actual memory location of `b[0]` to be stored in a different variable, and there is no other variable to store it in (`b` just has the actual elements, not a pointer).

Comment: @DanielH in C? I think, distinctiveness only plays role in C++ and if you don't use it as a an argument, C considers them compatible. Whole POSIX API and Linux ABI does it that way (enough just to look at sockets API and functions like sendmsg).
Under the circumstances, there's no difference at all. If you try to use an array type as a function parameter, the compiler will "adjust" that to a pointer type instead

Comment: Yes, I am certain. I first learned about this issue in a C context, and [here is a Compiler Explorer link in C](https://godbolt.org/g/Frf5Lm) where GCC not only says it's incompatible, it gives what would be the wrong answer if it were defined to work that way. Instead, it uses the first 64 bytes of the array as a pointer and dereferences that.

Comment: (Also, the parentheses are important; `bookings*[5]` is an array of five pointers to `bookings`, and that *can* be converted to `bookings**`.)

Comment: @DanielH your link is  http404

Comment: @Swift how `bookings(*)[5]` will be converted to `bookings**`?

Comment: That is odd; I can get to it just fine. Can you see Compiler Explorer not through my link? The code I used is `int double_deref(int** p) {
    return **p;
}

int main() {
    int arr[5] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    return double_deref(&arr);
}` (although with more useful whitespace than will be preserved in the comment), the language was set to C, and I compiled with gcc 7.3 and the options `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic -O3`. The warning options were unnecessary; the `-O3` helps to see what is actually happening without an excess of assembly to wade through.

Comment: I don't actually see any double pointers or pointers-to-array in `sendmsg` or `struct msghdr`, although I haven't looked at the message part of the sockets API enough to be sure I haven't missed something.

Comment: @DanielH Yeah, I agree. Looks like GCC is weird and code: `int double_deref(int* p) { return *p; } int main() {  int arr[5] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}; printf("%d", double_deref(&arr));  return  0;  } ` works in permissive mode. My way is more specific for PGI compilers apparenly, LLVM compilers family (gcc, clang..) does it diffrently. Curious. And Compiler Explorer doesn't work for me, they http503 me.

Comment: @DanielH  OP's code works as expected in GCC. I assume that's related issue, only -pedantic flag does this.

Comment: The code still gives the warning in GCC without `-pedantic`. It generates the desired code anyway for the same reason `bookings(*)[5]` is different from `bookings**`: an array is different from a pointer and is stored just as each of its elements in order, so a pointer to the array points to the same address as a pointer to the first element. As near as I can tell, C compilers are not required to provide *any* conversion, GCC-style or otherwise, so it makes sense that some compilers might try harder to do what they think you mean.